# HTTPS node server doesn't return web pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, marko

So I have just turned my HTTP web application to HTTPS.

So my server.js currently looks like

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8080);
```

This is a marko js project and my server.js used to look like

```
require("./project").server({
  httpPort: process.env.PORT || 8080 // Optional, but added here for demo purposes
});
```

Now currently when I navigate to any of the various web pages I have created such as localhost:8080/home I am only returned hello world. I assume this is due to the response I have in my create server method.

How do I go about returning my web pages as intended or would there be any resources that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Since you say you turned HTTP into HTTPS: Just use the same code you had for HTTP! Just use `https` instead of `http` in the code. (Or even better: Leave it at HTTP and use a reverse proxy such as [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/) to handle the SSL termination for you. Much less headache and no certificate fiddling.)

Answer (score 0):

did you already take a look at this howto?
https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + req.url, function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
      return;
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

It's working with `http` but I'd assume you can try `https` as well.

Just read the security concerns in the howto before going public with your server ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you have to handle requests:

> ```
> https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
>   res.writeHead(200);
>   res.end("hello world\n");
> }).listen(8080);
> ```

It doesn't matter what the browser asks for, the code you've written **always** responds with `hello world`.

If you want to respond with something different, then you need to pay attention to the `req` object, see what the browser is asking for and respond with something appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

> I am only returned hello world. I assume this is due to the response I have in my create server method.

If you are creating a server yourself, you're in charge of passing the content to the responses.  In your case, you're always passing `hello world`.  [This example](https://github.com/marko-js/examples/tree/master/examples/http) shows how to rendering Marko specifically when creating your own http server.

The gist is this.  Though if you have multiple pages, you'll need to render different templates depending on `req.url`.

```
const page = require('./path/to/page.marko');
https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  page.render({ data:123 }, res);
}).listen(8080);
```

However, it looks like you're using the `marko-starter` project.  So for this project, to enable `https` you can pass your `sslCert` and `sslKey` as options to the project config.

```
module.exports = require('marko-starter').projectConfig({
  sslKey: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  sslCert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
  /* other config */
});
```